# How to check my VS2008 service pack version?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How can i know what's the service pack version of VS2008? I merely know the version # is 9.0.30729.1 SP.

And what is the newest SP version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one Service Pack for Visual Studio 2008 and that is the one you have. There are only additional hotfixes that you can download from their website or using automatic updates.

Comment: Mine shows VS 2008 Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM and .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1. What are these? Is VS 2008 is SP1